# Importing function to new file not working

Tags: python, function, if-statement, import, module

My program is designed to create a module named MyTriangle that reads three sides of a triangle and computes the area if the input is valid. If the input is invalid, it will display "Input is invalid". The program works beautifully. The only problem is that I am trying to import module (everything except the main function) over into a different file. I have never done this before, and can't find anywhere that gives clear instructions. Here is my code:

```
side1, side2, side3 = eval(input("Enter three sides in a double: "))

def isValid(side1, side2, side3):

    return side1 + side2 > side3 and side1 + side3 > side2 and side2 + side3 > side1 

def area(side1, side2, side3):

    s = (side1 + side2 + side3) / 2;

    totalArea = (s * (s - side1) * (s - side2) * (s - side3)) ** 0.5    

    return totalArea

def main():  

    condition = isValid(side1, side2, side3)

    totalArea = area(side1, side2, side3)

    if condition:
        print("The area of the triangle is " + str(totalArea))
    else:
        print("input is invalid")

main()
```

I tried taking the "def main()" part and putting that into a file by itself. While naming the file with all the rest of the code "MyTriangle.py"

```
import MyTriangle
def main():  

    condition = isValid(side1, side2, side3)

    totalArea = area(side1, side2, side3)

    if condition:
        print("The area of the triangle is " + str(totalArea))
    else:
        print("input is invalid")

main()
```

When I run the program, it asks "Enter three sides in a double:".  When I put the numbers in (for example: 1, 1, 1), it says "name 'isValid' is not defined.  I am not sure if I am importing it over correctly or what. For the life of me, I cannot figure this out. A little help please?

Answer (score 2):

When you say `import myTriangle`, you are defining `myTriangle` as the other module.  Variables defined in that module are accessed as attributes of `myTriangle`.  You can use `myTriangle.isValid(...)` instead of `isValid(...)`.  Alternatively, you could say `from myTriangle import *` instead of `import myTriangle`.  Using `from myTriangle import *` puts all variables defined in `myTriangle` into the local namespace so that they can be accessed without putting `myTriangle` at the beginning.

Comment: I am not sure if that fixed it, because now once I enter the numbers into the program, I get nothing. Am I importing everything over correctly?

Comment: I would put `side1, side2, side3 = eval(...)` in the `main()` function.  You can keep the `main()` function in `myTriangle.py` and in the other script, just say `import myTriangle` `myTriangle.main()`.  I'm not sure why you want another script, though.

Comment: I tried what you said, unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: no error, it just showed nothing after I entered the numbers. It went to the next line. It is suppose to show the area of the numbers or an error message stating "input is invalid".

Comment: Ok, I really appreciate your help!